# group key based on value array php

Tags: php

I would like to make an array with group key's based on value's array.

For example, I have this array:

```
array(17) { 
    ["user-insert-resp.php"]=> string(3) "123" 
    ["login.php"]=> string(3) "123" 
    ["project-list.php"]=> string(3) "123" 
    ["logout.php"]=> string(3) "123" 
    ["index.php"]=> string(3) "123" 
    ["project-view.php"]=> string(2) "13" 
    ["download.php"]=> string(2) "13" 
    ["sip-creator-resp.php"]=> string(2) "23" 
    ["project-remove-resp.php"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["statistic.php"]=> string(2) "23" 
    ["graficoUsers.php"]=> string(2) "23" 
    ["statistic-topD.php"]=> string(2) "23" 
    ["statistic-topV.php"]=> string(2) "23" 
    ["user-edit-resp.php"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["statistic-proj.php"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["statistic-disc.php"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["graficodisc.php"]=> string(1) "3" 
}
```

and I want to make another array like this:

```
123 => ["user-insert-resp.php","login.php","project-list.php","logout.php","sip-creator-resp.php"]
13 => ["project-view.php","download.php"]
23 => ["sip-creator-resp.php","statistic.php","statistic-topD.php","statistic-topV.php"]
2 => ["project-remove-resp.php"];
3 => ["statistic-proj.php","statistic-disc.php","graficodisc.php"]
```

Comment: ... and what is the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$data = array();
$data["user-insert-resp.php"] = "123";
$data["login.php"] = "123";
$data["project-view.php"] = "13";


$flipped_data = array();
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    if(!isset($flipped_data[$value])){
        $flipped_data[$value] = array();
    }
    $flipped_data[$value][] = $key;
}
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
[123] => Array ( [0] => user-insert-resp.php [1] => login.php ) 
[13] => Array ( [0] => project-view.php )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have easily found `array_flip()` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php .